# vuejs 3 y laravel 9, no renderiza componente

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue3, laravel-9

Estoy tratando de hacer un datatable con VUE 3, he instalado y configurado vue y demás. la librería que uso para esto es: `vue-good-table-next`

He creado el componente

```
<template>
  <div>
    <vue-good-table :columns="columns" :rows="rows" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'datatableFisios',
        mounted(){
            console.log(`The initial count is.`)
        },
        data(){
            return {
                
                columns: [
                    {
                        label: 'Name',
                        field: 'name',
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Age',
                        field: 'age',
                        type: 'number',
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Created On',
                        field: 'createdAt',
                        type: 'date',
                        dateInputFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd',
                        dateOutputFormat: 'MMM do yy',
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Percent',
                        field: 'score',
                        type: 'percentage',
                    },
                ],
                    rows: [
                        { id:1, name:"John", age: 20, createdAt: '',score: 0.03343 },
                        { id:2, name:"Jane", age: 24, createdAt: '2011-10-31', score: 0.03343 },
                        { id:3, name:"Susan", age: 16, createdAt: '2011-10-30', score: 0.03343 },
                        { id:4, name:"Chris", age: 55, createdAt: '2011-10-11', score: 0.03343 },
                        { id:5, name:"Dan", age: 40, createdAt: '2011-10-21', score: 0.03343 },
                        { id:6, name:"John", age: 20, createdAt: '2011-10-31', score: 0.03343 },
                    ],
                };
        },
    };
</script>
```

Y añadido al app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');


import { createApp } from "vue";
import datatableFisios from "./components/datatableFisios.vue";

createApp({
    components: {
        datatableFisios,
    },
}).mount("#app");
```

y lo he añadido a mi blade:

```
<div id="app" class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">
   <!-- esta tabla se crea desde VUEJS -->
   <datatableFisios></datatableFisios>
</div>
```

Y cuando cargo en el navegador me aparece este warning y no me carga el componente:

```
VM2547 app.js:7109 [Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function. 
  at <App>
warn @ VM2547 app.js:7109
finishComponentSetup @ VM2547 app.js:14342
setupStatefulComponent @ VM2547 app.js:14239
setupComponent @ VM2547 app.js:14161
mountComponent @ VM2547 app.js:12516
processComponent @ VM2547 app.js:12491
patch @ VM2547 app.js:12090
render @ VM2547 app.js:13252
mount @ VM2547 app.js:11465
app.mount @ VM2547 app.js:16648
(anónimo) @ VM2547 app.js:55050
(anónimo) @ VM2547 app.js:55051
(anónimo) @ VM2547 app.js:55053
app.js:7109 [Vue warn]: There is already an app instance mounted on the host container.
 If you want to mount another app on the same host container, you need to unmount the previous app by calling `app.unmount()` first.
```

Alguien por favor, sabría decirme que estoy haciendo mal¿?

Gracias por leerme y la ayuda

Comment: En tu componente datatableFisios no tendrías que importar vue-good-table y agregarlo a la propiedad components?

Answer (score 0):

Te falta importar la librería que utilizas para la datatable:

Puedes importarla en el componente que la utilizas de este modo:

```
// import the styles
import 'vue-good-table/dist/vue-good-table.css'
import { VueGoodTable } from 'vue-good-table';

// add to component
components: {
  VueGoodTable,
}
```

O importarla globalmente de este modo:

```
import VueGoodTablePlugin from 'vue-good-table';

// import the styles
import 'vue-good-table/dist/vue-good-table.css'

Vue.use(VueGoodTablePlugin);
```